# Get the email address of a "people chip"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Does anyone know if there is a way to use the Google Sheets API to get the email address of a [people chip](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135869067/google-sheets-people-chips?hl=en)? It seems like the only values it will give me are the person's full name as displayed in the cell.

While trying to figure this out I discovered that the name turns into an email address if you use  "Format > Clear Formatting". I hoped I could hack this by copying the value into a hidden sheet, clearing the formatting, and then get the email address there. But though Google Apps Script has a function for executing that on a cell, I have found no way to do it with the Sheets API. I tried clearing all the possible formats I could via batchUpdate with an updateCellsRequest but that isn't turning the people chip into an email address.

I'm at the point where if I really want to automate this, I will need to use the `scripts` API as well, to deploy and execute a tiny Apps Script just to run clearFormat on a cell. I'd like to avoid this much complication, especially since Apps Script doesn't work for service accounts.

Comment: In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that Sheets API cannot manage the smart chips. So how about reporting it to Google issue tracker as the future request? [Ref}(https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned this is not possible at the moment but there is already a feature request in the Google Issue tracker related to adding the people chips to the Sheets API. You can check the request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225584757).

I would suggest posting a comment on it and explain why you are interested in this feature. Or if you think your request has a different approach you can also submit a new feature request for the Sheets API [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#missing_features).

Comment: Thanks, I just filed 2 issues: [Read Smart Chip values from Google Sheets (API)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227045287) and ["Clear formatting" API call](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226925201)