# Search for People Chips in a Google Doc and Replace it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-gsuite

I'm trying to create a script to find and replace every Person chip in a google doc with their handle on a different platform.

My original thought was to create a Google Sheet with the chip and the corresponding handle and cycle through that, but having a hard time figuring out how to parse through the google doc and find the related chip to begin with.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible in Google Apps Script

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71621663/google-sheets-api-get-the-email-address-of-a-people-chip

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.