# Use SmartChips as part of a formula | Retrieve Calender Events automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of dates (<=TODAY) in Google Sheets.
For each row I'd like to show all calendar events corresponding to the date, if existing.
If possible I'd like to use the SmartChips feature but i don't know how to extend this over several rows while connecting it to the column containing the dates.
I'm aware of solutions via AppScript but would like to avoid that if possible - or at least use SmartChips in combination with AppScript.
Do you know if preferably the former but at least the latter is possible?
Cheers

Comment: I’m afraid that smart chips aren’t optimized to be used in formulas or through the API, at this stage you can only interact with them in a meaningful way through the web view. I actually found a similar answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624408) and that OP created a Feature Request to enhance he feature available for Smart Chips, you can either add a '+' to raise visibility of that feature request or make your own [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/support#developer_product_feedback) requesting the ability to use them in formulas as well.